# How to remove exterior punctuation from a string using regular expressions

Tags: java, regex, string, java.util.scanner, delimiter

Given a string like below, remove any leading and trailing punctuation via regular expressions:

```
String a = "!?Don't.;, .:delete !the@ $actual string%";
String b = "Hyphenated-words, too!";
```

I know that the regex [\P{Alnum}] will target all non-alphanumeric characters, but how do I target ONLY the leading and trailing punctuation so I get...

```
a = "Don't delete the actual string";
b = "Hyphenated-words too";
```

... instead of:

```
a = "Dont delete the actual string";
b = "Hyphenated words too";
```

I just need the regular expression; not the actual code to remove the punctuation.

Comment: When you say "leading and trailing", doesn't that mean that the result should be `Don't.;, .:delete !the@ $actual string`? What is "leading" or "trailing" about, for example, the `@` which is not applicable to the `'` in `Don't`? And, incidentally, asking for a regex is asking for code. Don't do that.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I meant "leading"/"trailing" punctuation for each word in the string, and not necessarily for the string itself. I did not clearly indicate that I was using a scanner delimiter (that's why I just needed the regex and not the whole code itself). As for your last comment, I was not aware that asking for a regex was asking for code; and I apologize in advance.

Comment: what result you want to get this **a = "Don't delete the actual string";
b = "Hyphenated-words too";** or this **a = "Dont delete the actual string";
b = "Hyphenated words too";**

Comment: @J.Adder I have updated my answer to use `\p{Punct}` now, as per sln's comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to match punctuation that is adjacent to a) a whitespace character OR b) the beginning or end.

- your pattern preceded by `(?<=^|\s)` positive lookbehind, or
- your pattern followed by `(?=\s|$)` positive lookahead

To shorten the pattern, we could reword this a little bit to say that our punctuation block must either a) not preceded by some character that's not a whitespace or b) not followed by a  character that's not a whitespace.

- your pattern preceded by `(?<!\S)` negative lookbehind, or
- your pattern followed by `(?!\S)` negative lookahead

As a final note, you should use `\p{Punct}` instead of `[\P{Alnum}]` to match punctuation. See the [comment by sln](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/73457759) for details.

Here is an example usage:

```
String a = "!?Don't.;, .:delete !the@ $actual string%";
String b = "Hyphenated-words, too!";
String regex = "(?:(?<!\\S)\\p{Punct}+)|(?:\\p{Punct}+(?!\\S))";
System.out.println(a.replaceAll(regex, ""));
System.out.println(b.replaceAll(regex, ""));
```

**Output:**

> Don't delete the actual string
>
> Hyphenated-words too

Comment: it still a small thing, for example this **Hyphenated---words, too!** i believe you can do it good luck

Comment: @YCF_L What is your desired output for the input of "Hyphenated---words, too!"? My understanding is that the "---" is not leading or trailing the word, but rather in the middle of the word, and therefore should remain unchanged. Consider also "Mac-'Dougal." Please do a better job explaining what you want.

Comment: ah ok, this is my bad then, you aready get my up vote good luck ;)

Comment: This is an incomplete solution. `\P{Alnum}` covers all whitespace as well which effectively strips off all formatting and the other voluminous Unicode codepoints that aren't punctuation. If you were to use this approach at least exclude whitespace `(?:(?<!\S)[^\p{Alnum}\s]+)|(?:[^\p{Alnum}\s]+(?!\S))`

Comment: @sln Good point. I ran with OP's assumption that he wanted to use  `[\P{Alnum}]` but upon closer inspection that was a horrible assumption.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `^` and `$`. `^` matches the start of the string and `$` the end. The regex `^\W*` should match all non-alphanumeric character in the beginning and `\W*$` those in the end. You can simply replace these regexes with an empty string to get rid of the non-alphanumeric characters. Obviously, you have to escape the `\` in the Java string (assuming you are using Java).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regular expression:

[`(?:[^\w\s]*)(\S*?)[^\w\s]*(?=\s|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/PQzYZy/1)

And substitute by

**$1**

For your sample input, the output is:

> Don't delete the actual string
>   Hyphenated-words too

NB: I have used `\w`, but if you need the more precise definition of alphanumeric, then replace the two `\w` by `\p{Alnum}`.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably not much left after punct and alnum (except ctrl's).
May as well leverage that by using *whitespace boundary's*.

**Find:**
Raw  `(?<!\S)(?:\p{punct}*(\p{alnum}+(?:\p{punct}?\p{alnum})*)\p{punct}*|\p{punct}+)(?!\S)`
Stringed  `"(?<!\\S)(?:\\p{punct}*(\\p{alnum}+(?:\\p{punct}?\\p{alnum})*)\\p{punct}*|\\p{punct}+)(?!\\S)"`

**Replace** `"$1"`

Explained

```
 (?<! \S )                             # Whitespace boundary
 (?:                                   # Cluster
      \p{punct}*                            # Optional punct
      (                                     # (1 start), words to be written back
           \p{alnum}+                            # Required, start with alnum
           (?: \p{punct}? \p{alnum} )*           # Optional punct + alnum 
      )                                     # (1 end)
      \p{punct}*                            # Optional punct
   |                                      # or,
      \p{punct}+                            # Required punct
 )                                     # End Cluster
 (?! \S )                              # Whitespace boundary
```

Target before

```
!?Don't.;, .:delete !the@ ()*& $actual string%
Hyphenated-words,  a)
```

Target after replace

```
Don't delete the  actual string
Hyphenated-words  a
```

Comment: note: Since OP wants regex for use as "a scanner delimiter", he won't be able to directly make use of any answers involving `$1` or similar.